# How to compile a subset of all targets in a CMake-generated Makefile that start with a given prefix in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell, cmake, makefile, target

I want to write a shell script that will only compile and execute the unit test binaries in my project. All targets in the `Makefile` (generated by CMake) associated with unit tests begin with `UnitTest`, e.g. `UnitTestArray`. How can I write a for loop in the shell script to individually compile all unit test binaries? I know how to sequentially run the pre-compiled binaries in a loop. It's just the compilation part that I am uncertain about. See my shell script below.

```
WORKDIR=$PWD
BUILD=~/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build
BIN=$BUILD/bin

# Compile test binaries
cd $BUILD
for target in [UnitTest* in Makefile] # I'm not sure how to write this for loop.
do
  echo ""
  echo "Compiling $target" 
  make -j 8 $target 
done

# Run tests
cd $BIN
for test in UnitTest*
do
  echo ""
  echo "Running $test" 
  ./$test 
done

cd $WORKDIR
```

The following are some example target rules in the generated Makefile:

```
#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named UnitTestApeiron

# Build rule for target.
UnitTestApeiron: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 UnitTestApeiron
.PHONY : UnitTestApeiron

# fast build rule for target.
UnitTestApeiron/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/UnitTestApeiron.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/UnitTestApeiron.dir/build
.PHONY : UnitTestApeiron/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named UnitTestArray

# Build rule for target.
UnitTestArray: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 UnitTestArray
.PHONY : UnitTestArray

# fast build rule for target.
UnitTestArray/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/UnitTestArray.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/UnitTestArray.dir/build
.PHONY : UnitTestArray/fast
```

Comment: Not sure I completely understand but why not just add an appropriate `BuildAllUnitTests` target to the `makefile`?

Comment: @G.M. So I generate the Makefile using cmake. And I would prefer to not have to manually add each new unit test target into a separate target. I hope I'm making sense?

Comment: @G.M. Or is there a much easier way to do this in cmake itself? That is, to create a separate target that only compiles the unit test binaries.

Comment: ```target in [UnitTest* in Makefile]``` - I think you can parse Makefile and extract UnitTest names. Please attach example of Makefile

Comment: @Saboteur The Makefile is 400 lines long. Can you suggest how I can attach it to this post?

Comment: You should have led off with the fact that your makefiles are generated by CMake.  CMake-generated makefiles are very recursive and very complicated.  I think parsing them will be quite a chore.  Why don't you just use ctest etc. as suggested by @niran90?

Comment: Rather than including the entire makefile you can include some samples of the types of rules you want to run.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the suggestion. I have also made a note in the post that I generated the Makefile via CMake.

Comment: @MadScientist It looks like CTest is the ideal solution here. I will do a bit more reading up on it. Thank you :)

Comment: ctest is probably your best bet but, if you want, you can use a command like this to extract the names of the unit tests: `sed -n 's,^\(UnitTest[^/]*\):.*,\1,p' Makefile` (based on the content you provided above)

Comment: @niran90, as I can see all UnitTest names could be found with such strings:
UnitTestArray: cmake_check_build_system

so just grep "cmake_check_build_system" and cut first column with ":" separator
```grep "cmake_check_build_system" Makefile|cut -d":" -f1```

Comment: @Saboteur That's a great idea! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to the solutions suggested by users @MadScientist and @Saboteur in the above comments. The following is the modification of my shell script using @Saboteur's solution:

```
WORKDIR=$PWD
BUILD=~/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build
BIN=$BUILD/bin

# Compile test binaries
cd $BUILD
declare -a TargetList=$(grep "cmake_check_build_system" $BUILD/Makefile|cut -d":" -f1)
for target in ${TargetList[@]}; do
  # Check if target keyword contains the substring "UnitTest"
  if grep -q "UnitTest" <<< "$target"; then
     printf "\nCompiling $target\n" 
     make -j 16 $target
  fi
done

# Run tests
cd $BIN
for test in UnitTest*
do
  printf "\nRunning $test\n" 
  ./$test 
done

cd $WORKDIR
```

This yields the following output:

```
$ ./unit_test.sh 
Compiling UnitTestArray
[ 16%] Building CXX object _deps/googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libgtest.a
[ 33%] Built target gtest
[ 50%] Building CXX object _deps/googletest-build/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libgtest_main.a
[ 66%] Built target gtest_main
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/UnitTestArray.dir/libs/DataContainers/test/UnitTestArray.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/UnitTestArray
[100%] Built target UnitTestArray

Compiling UnitTestApeiron
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target gtest
[ 33%] Built target gtest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target gtest_main
[ 66%] Built target gtest_main
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/UnitTestApeiron.dir/test/UnitTestApeiron.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/UnitTestApeiron
[100%] Built target UnitTestApeiron

Running UnitTestApeiron
Running main() from /home/niran90/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 15 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 15 tests from ApeironTest
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Min
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Min (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Max
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Max (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.MinMax
[       OK ] ApeironTest.MinMax (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Bound
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Bound (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Sgn
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Sgn (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Abs
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Abs (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Floor
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Floor (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Ceil
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Ceil (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.Round
[       OK ] ApeironTest.Round (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isEqual
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isEqual (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isLess
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isLess (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isLessEqual
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isLessEqual (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isLarger
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isLarger (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isLargerEqual
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isLargerEqual (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] ApeironTest.isBounded
[       OK ] ApeironTest.isBounded (0 ms)
[----------] 15 tests from ApeironTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 15 tests from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 15 tests.

Running UnitTestArray
Running main() from /home/niran90/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from ArrayTest
[ RUN      ] ArrayTest.Initialisation
[       OK ] ArrayTest.Initialisation (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ArrayTest.AssignmentOperator
[       OK ] ArrayTest.AssignmentOperator (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from ArrayTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

I can see @MadScientist's suggestion to use CTest being very useful when the number of `gtest` unit tests is quite large. This is because CTest provides a concise summary of the passed/failed tests. I had to configure my project CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
enable_testing()

# Fetch GoogleTest directories
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(GoogleTest URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(GoogleTest)

# Add unit test executables
add_executable(UnitTestApeiron ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/UnitTestApeiron.cpp)
add_executable(UnitTestArray ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/DataContainers/test/UnitTestArray.cpp)

# Link with gtest, gtest_main, and associated libraries.
target_link_libraries(UnitTestApeiron gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(UnitTestArray gtest gtest_main)

add_test(UnitTestApeiron ${BIN_DIRECTORY}/UnitTestApeiron)
add_test(UnitTestArray ${BIN_DIRECTORY}/UnitTestArray)
```

Then, simply running `ctest` in the project build directory gives:

```
$ ctest 
Test project /home/niran90/Dropbox/Projects/Apeiron/build
    Start 1: UnitTestApeiron
1/2 Test #1: UnitTestApeiron ..................   Passed    0.01 sec
    Start 2: UnitTestArray
2/2 Test #2: UnitTestArray ....................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.01 sec
```